# Cannot set property of undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a json object s.BdayDetails and i want to change the values of my s.BdayDetails.ProvID into another value.

```
 for(var i=0;i<s.BdayDetails.length;i++){
```

h.post("../Event/getProvinceName?ProvID=" + s.BdayDetails[i].ProvID).then(function (r) {

s.BdayDetails[i].ProvID = r.data.toString();


            })

Returns an error Cannot set property 'ProvID' of undefined. But when I console.log(r.data.toString()) it shows the values.

Comment: It is s.BdayDetails[i].ProvID that is undefined. There's nothing to do with r.

Comment: It seems like you are doing multiple async AJAX request inside for loop. You should avoid multiple AJAX like this and write logic so that you can do the same with one AJAX call.

Comment: How? sorry im new to this :(

Comment: When the async AJAX finishes the value of `i` is not available.

Comment: im so confused rn hahaha :D thanks

Comment: can you post a code ?

Comment: send the entire `BdayDetails` to the server in a single AJAX  and modify the required attributes on server. Then send back the result to client.

Comment: is there another way without sending it to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the below code to achieve the same as you described. Please check with this [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/MljCPRfX9MkRw0DRg3HE?p=catalogue) for the example code implementation.

**Controller:**

```
  var s ={
    BdayDetails: [{
      ProvID: '001',
      ProvName: 'KARNATAKA'
    },{
      ProvID: '002',
      ProvName: 'GOA'
    }]
  };
  var indx = 0;

  function nextProvince(){
    if(indx < s.BdayDetails.length){
      $http.post("../Event/getProvinceName?ProvID=" + s.BdayDetails[indx].ProvID).then(function (r) {
          s.BdayDetails[indx].ProvID = r.data.toString();
          indx++;
          nextProvince();
      });
    }else{
      indx=0;
    }
  }
  nextProvince();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

[This is called closure inside the loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```
for(var i=0;i<s.BdayDetails.length;i++){
   function(index){
        h.post("../Event/getProvinceName?ProvID=" + s.BdayDetails[i].ProvID).then(function (r) {
            s.BdayDetails[index].ProvID = r.data.toString();
        })
   })(i);
 }
}
```